# how to expand a list outside a backquote - macrodefinition

Tags: common-lisp

I am trying to implement a macro which expands a unlimited list of triplet-arguments into lambda-function to check an argument (object).

e.g.

```
(where >= amount 5 equalp name "george")

=>

#'(lambda (arg)
          (and
            (>= (amount arg) 5)
            (equalp (name arg) "george")))
```

I got quite close with this macrodefinition:

```
(defmacro where (&rest list-of-argument-triplets )
   `#'(lambda (arg)
        (and
          ,(do ( (counter 0 (+ counter 3)) (liste (list)))
               ( (>= counter (list-length list.of-argument-triplets)) liste)
                 (push `( ,(nth counter list-of-argument-triplets)
                          ( ,(nth (+ counter 1) list-of-argument-triplets) arg)
                          ,(nth (+ counter 2) list-of-argument-triplets)
                          liste)))))
```

but this expands to

```
#'(lambda (arg)
    (and ((>= (amount arg) 5)
          (equalp (name arg) "george"))))
```

which is one parentheses after the "and" too much. As a conclusion I would have to use an @ in front of the result-form, but then the "@list" is treated
as if it is an parameter-name, and therefore I get an no-value error, instead of an expanded list.

```
        *** - RETURN-FROM: variable @LISTE has no value
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code smell: you use NTH to access elements of a list.

I would first define a helper function, which makes out of the flat list a list of three element lists:

```
(defun triplets (list)
  (loop while list
        collect (list (pop list)
                      (pop list)
                      (pop list))))

CL-USER 1 > (triplets '(a b c d e f g h i))
((A B C) (D E F) (G H I))
```

The macro is then slightly simpler to write:

```
(defmacro where (&rest flat-triplets)
  `#'(lambda (arg)
       (and
         ,@(mapcar (lambda (triplet)
                     (destructuring-bind (fn accessor item)
                         triplet
                       `(,fn (,accessor arg) ,item)))
                   (triplets flat-triplets))))


CL-USER 2 > (macroexpand-1 '(where >= amount 5 equalp name "george"))
(FUNCTION (LAMBDA (ARG) (AND (>= (AMOUNT ARG) 5) (EQUALP (NAME ARG) "george"))))
T
```

Comment: thank you, it does work. But just as a lesson:
1 - Why is nth as an accessor bad style? 2 - Would be possible to apply a fix to may approach?

Comment: @Sim: if you want access elements by index, then use an array. Lists in Lisp are linked lists. So you need to traverse the list to access the nth element - every time. The cheapest operations are FIRST and REST. Then use list operations like MAPCAR - instead of iterations like DO.